# Django error on deleting a user in the admin interface

Tags: django, django-models

Somewhere between my development machine and my deployment machine (still in testing thank god), the migrations got jumbled. I am not sure what is going on or how to fix, I found the error just by simply going to the admin and deleting a user.

I think the migrations got jumbled between my development box and deployment box (thats still in testing thank god)

When I try this the web page (I put the whole application into Debug=True in the settings) says:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/auth/user/
column programscheduler_proposal.scheduler_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...duler_proposal" INNER JOIN "accounts_apouser" ON ("programsc...
```

I am thinking my migrations and many to manys got messed up. I went ahead and loaded the database in postgres and showed some tables:

```
 public             | programscheduler_instrument           | django_apodb_user |            | t          | f        | t           | f
 public             | programscheduler_quarterschedule      | django_apodb_user |            | t          | f        | t           | f
 public             | programscheduler_proposalobserver     | django_apodb_user |            | t          | f        | t           | f
 public             | programscheduler_proposalconstraint   | django_apodb_user |            | t          | f        | t           | f
 public             | programscheduler_institutionallotment | django_apodb_user |            | t          | f        | t           | f
 public             | accounts_apouser                      | django_apodb_user |            | t          | f        | t           | f
```

I see the error, I see it is busted but cannot figure out how it is busted or how it got that way?

So the models being referenced are:

```
from django.db import models



class InstitutionAllotment(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()

    quarter = models.CharField(max_length = 15) #this should be more... exact? (use a date field?)
    institution = models.ForeignKey("mainpage.Institution", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    max_allotment = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 4, decimal_places=2) #might have to change this
    current_allotment = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 4, decimal_places=2) #might have to change this
    remaining_allotment = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 4, decimal_places=2) #might have to change this
    



class Instrument(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    inst_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)


class ProposalObserver(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    proposal = models.ForeignKey("Proposal", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    observer = models.ForeignKey("mainpage.InstitutionMember", on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class Program(models.Model):
    programName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    institution = models.ForeignKey("mainpage.Institution", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


#should act as blackout constraints

class ProposalConstraint(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    proposal = models.ForeignKey("Proposal", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date_time_constraint = models.DateTimeField()
    note = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    isPersonal = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Proposal(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()    
    program = models.ForeignKey("Program", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    institution = models.ForeignKey("mainpage.Institution", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    scheduler = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pi = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  
    untrained_observer_list = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    collaborators = models.CharField(max_length=200) 

    contact_information = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #instrument = models.ForeignKey("Instrument", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    instrument = models.ManyToManyField("Instrument") 

    primary_dis_grating = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
    secondary_dis_grating = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    slits = models.CharField(max_length=150) 
    filters = models.CharField(max_length=150) 
    targetofop = models.CharField(max_length =200, null=True, blank=True) 
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
    time_request_dark = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    time_request_grey = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    time_request_bright = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    science_justification = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pre_emption_protection = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    publication = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    approved_on = models.DateField()
    isApproved = models.BooleanField()
    reviewed = models.BooleanField()




class QuarterSchedule(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    quarter = models.CharField(max_length = 15) #this should be more... exact? (use a date field?)
    institution = models.ForeignKey("mainpage.Institution", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then under accounts

```
class APOUser(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    

    institution =  models.ForeignKey("mainpage.Institution", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    gender = models.ForeignKey("mainpage.GenderTable", on_delete=models.SET_NULL,  null=True)
    on_site_status = models.ForeignKey("mainpage.SiteStatus", on_delete=models.SET_NULL,  null=True)
    refer_to_as = models.TextField(max_length = 30, blank=True, null=True) #if the above is custom

    #THIS CAUSES CICULAR DEPENDANCY
    room_preference  = models.ForeignKey("housing.Room", on_delete=models.SET_NULL,  null=True)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
            return str(self.user.first_name) + " " + str(self.user.last_name)
```

So I appreciate the software giving me a hint but no idea what its really telling me? (plus the full select query is truncated :/)

I did check the debug.log I define in the settings it does not give much more information:

```
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/workers/apo_web/apo_web/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/workers/apo_web/apo_web/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/workers/apo_web/apo_web/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/workers/apo_web/apo_web/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/workers/apo_web/apo_web/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/workers/apo_web/apo_web/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column programscheduler_proposal.program_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "programscheduler_proposal"."id", "programscheduler_p...
                                                 ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "programscheduler_proposal.programID".
```

So going by the models.py it is there.  I also tried as suggested to start fresh wwith a:

```
 python3 manage.py migrate programscheduler zero
```

That just gave a new error:

```
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/workers/apo_web/apo_web/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/workers/apo_web/apo_web/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/workers/apo_web/apo_web/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: table "programscheduler_proposal_instrument" does not exist
```

Witch according to models.py it does exsist.

Comment: It tells that you are referencing the column in the database that does not exist: programscheduler_proposal.program_id. This all that can be seen from your post. Try setting up LOGGING in Django, and getting more info.