# removing added django application from a database

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I just posted another question:

[Django error on deleting a user in the admin interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76175376/django-error-on-deleting-a-user-in-the-admin-interface)

But realized in that question the project /models it is complaining about I am going a different direction with. So I was curious how I can I just remove a project from the database. i.e. a whole folder under my django application?  I will be redoing it anyway and I want my deployed application from the earlier question to keep working along.  Is it just a matter of removing all the data in models.py and then doing a new migration?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to completely remove the database tables that were created for the models in your app. You can do this using the command `migrate <app> zero`. From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#migrate:

> Use the name `zero` to migrate all the way back i.e. to revert all applied migrations for an app.

Comment: I will try this thanks!  I need to figure out what broke these migrations so bad :( .  One of my models doesn't help it has a circular dependency I don't know how to fix but I get around that by migrating in a special order iirc.   Thanks though I will try this and hope it fixes my issue!

Comment: Ahhhh I tried this and it failed because it said: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: table "programscheduler_proposal_instrument" does not exist  added model in question for completeness.

Comment: Hm, not sure I can help debug that. Sorry!

Comment: Is there away where I can basically wipe out the entire database and start from fresh with my migrations?

Comment: Yes for sure. What kind of database are you using? The default is SQLite, in which case you should be able to simple delete that local file (I think it'll be named something like db.sqlite3). If you're using Postgres or Mysql though, you'll need to open up a console and delete/recreate the database.

Comment: for the dev environment which is the one giving me an issue is postgres.